# Why am I getting a syntax error in this SQL code?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a task that needs to be solved using an SQL query in MS Acess: "In which dormitory students from not all groups live".
My table is called `Dormitories` and it has columns `Student_name`, `Student_group`, `Dormitory_name`.

I am trying to solve it like this:

```sql
SELECT Dormitory_name
FROM Dormitories
GROUP BY Dormitory_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Student_group) < (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Student_group) FROM Dormitories)
```

But I constantly get out "Syntax error (lack of operator)" in the last line. Explain what's wrong

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you’re using. Answers can vary materially between each.

Comment: That's not what Having is for...you need that to be a where clause.

Comment: I am doing this in MS Access

Comment: @NevilleKuyt If `having` is not for that, what is it for?

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result are crucial.

Comment: Where is to filter records based on a condition. Having is to filter rows based on an aggregate, e.g. "show me dormitories and the number of students in that dormitory, but only for dormitories with at least 3 students".

Comment: @NevilleKuyt And like you said, the rows here are filtered based on an aggregate, namely, `count(distinct Student_group)`. How are you going to put that in a `where`?

Comment: There is no aggregate in your select - that would be "select dormitory_name, count(*) from...having count(*) > (select count(*)...)"

Comment: @NevilleKuyt That is not my `select`. How does the absence of an aggregate in the `select` portion of the query affect the presence of an aggregate in the `having` portion of the query? It is the fact that you are filtering on an aggregate that makes you use `having`, not the fact that you are selecting an aggregate. Can you demonstrate how you would put `COUNT(DISTINCT Student_group) < (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Student_group) FROM Dormitories)` in a `where`?